# Avoid autowiring beans created with factory

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, autowired

I have a web application developed with Spring MVC. This application has to consume a bean from a library which has Spring annotations:

```
@Service
public class DefaultSampleService implements SampleService {
    @Autowired SampleRepository sampleRepository;

    //Methods of service
}
```

I can not scan for this bean in my application So, despite having Spring annotations, I have to instantiate this bean by a factory provided by the library.

```
<beans>
    <bean id="libraryFactory" class="com.company.LibraryFactory" />

    <bean id="sampleService" factory-bean="libraryFactory" factory-method="getSampleService" />
</beans>
```

The factory returns a sampleService bean with sampleRepository property filled. However, I get an NoSuchBeanDefinitionException when the application loads the xml configuration because Spring doesn't found a bean of SampleRepository.

It's true that there is not a SampleRepository bean in the beanFactory of Spring. But I don't need it, because sampleService is instantiated by a factory and its properties are filled.

**How can I prevent the autowiring process with sampleService bean?**

I've tried to add the attribute autowire="no" to the sampleService definition, but it doesn't work.

```
<bean id="sampleService" factory-bean="libraryFactory" factory-method="getSampleService" autowire="no" />
```

This is the stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.company.lib.repositories.SampleRepository com.company.lib.services.DefaultSampleService.sampleRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.company.lib.repositories.SampleRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.company.lib.repositories.SampleRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:986)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:856)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 56 more
```

Comment: You need to specify a class for the sampleService bean. Just because you provide a factory method, Spring doesn't know what kind of object is going to be returned by the factory method. Do you know the location of this class?

Comment: I think the class attribute must be defined only when the instantiation is done with static factory. In this case, I'm using an instance factory method and I believe the class has not to be provided. Here there is Spring's documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-class-instance-factory-method

Comment: Can you show the complete stacktrace?

Comment: Thanks for the stacktrace! Can you explain why you don't need the `SampleRepository`? Doesn't `DefaultSampleService ` call any methods of `SampleRepository`?

Comment: Yes, DefaultSampleService calls methods of SampleRepository. But DefaultSampleService created with the factory has the SampleRepository filled. So, despite having @Autowired, I don't need Spring trying to autowire this property because it has been filled previously.

Comment: Then why have `@Autowired` in the first place if you don't want to Spring to do the autowiring? Remove the annotation.

Comment: I know that the annotation should be removed or add the attribute required=false, but unfortunately I can not manage that. So I wonder if there is another way using XML to tell Spring don't autowire the proper ties because they have been filled.

Comment: If the problem is that the library is being scanned by `component-scan`, then you need to put filters into your `component-scan` to exclude the packages you want to avoid.  However, there is no reason you cannot mix XML loaded beans and auto-scanned beans in the same application.